# swift 3.0 Problems about String initialization

Tags: swift, string

I am quite new to Swift and when I learning about initializing a string, I find a wired syntax that I cannot understand.

For example
If I initialize a string using:

```
 var str:String = "Hello, playground"
    str.isEmpty
```

This works well

However, if I initialize a string with a constructor

```
var str = String("Hello, playground")
str.isEmpty
```

this does not work.
And the compiler fix it by changing the syntax to

```
str?.isEmpty
```

I have no idea about what is that “?” for. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/beginners-guide-optionals-swift/

Comment: Read the Swift manual, chapter "Optionals". Very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
let str = String("Hello, playground")
```

you're using `String`'s [`init?(_ description: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540435-init) initialiser, which satisfies [`LosslessStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/losslessstringconvertible)'s initialiser requirement, as not all types that conform have a representation for an *arbitrary* string (for example, `Double`).

Because the initialiser is failable, it returns an optional string instance (i.e `String?`), hence why the compiler is prompting you to use optional chaining (if not already, I would highly recommend reading the [optionals section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)).

However it's worth noting there's *absolutely* no need for `String`'s implementation of this initialiser to be failable – as a string can always represent a string! This [will be fixed in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/807410b99ef2473f25df8c53b36eead869883800), it will be implemented as a non-failable initialiser satisfying the failable requirement. This is because it doesn't break the contract with the protocol of either returning a new instance *or* `nil` (it just never happens to do the latter).

In the mean time however, you *could* just force unwrap the result, as it will always succeed. But really the use of the initialiser here is completely redundant. You should use a string literal, such as in your first example:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
```

`str` will simply be initialised to a non-optional `String` instance with the contents of the string literal. Note that Swift can *infer* `str` to be of type `String` – you don't need to explicitly annotate it as such.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that (as in this case) a non-failable initializer can satisfy the protocol requirement of a failable initializer (or "initialiser", as you would say :)

Comment: @MartinR And yeah... don't get me started on the americani**s**ation of words ;)

Answer (score 0):

var str = String("Hello, playground")

This produces what is called an "Optional".  In Swift, if something can be null/nil, then it is wrapped in an Optional.  The '?' tries to unwrap the optional and produce a String.

If you KNOW that the value can never be null, then you can force unwrap it like this:

```
var str = String("Hello, playground")
str!.isEmpty
```

or

```
var str2 = String("Hello, playground")!
str2.isEmpty
```

Generally though forced unwrapping is frowned upon, as it can lead to crashes.  Better approaches:

```
struct MyError:Error {
    var message:String
}

guard let str3 = String("Hello, playground") else {
    throw MyError(message:"failed")
}
str3.isEmpty


if let str4 = String("Hello, playground") {
    str4.isEmpty
}
```